# view is not getting inflated after a fragment is added on the framelayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I have a strange problem,  i placed my layout files in layout-large-land(landscape mode) folder and and  added a fragment on button click... that fragment is correctly inflated , but if i try to add more fragments from that fragment i get the issue the view is not showing, i tried to toast a message in the oncreateView, strangely the toast is showing but the view is not showing, the strange part is the code for portrait mode is working fine, i am a newbie to android can anybody help..

this is my fragment call

```
chooseActivity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("captain");
                addFragment(new ChooseActivityFragment(), true,
                        FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE, "choose_activity");
            }
        });
```

This is the added fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("-----oncreateview");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_activity_new, container,
                false);

        System.out.println("-----oncreateview inside:" + view.getId());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "oncreate view choose activity", 1)
                .show();
            return view;
 }
```

here is my code to add fragment

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack,
            int transition, String name) {
        System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");

        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        // ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, CouponsFragment);
        ft.add(R.id.tabContent, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(name);

        ft.commit();
    }
```